# Looking for help creating dry code with dynamic naming inside mongoose/mongodb functions/methods

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm a bootcamp student, an old guy but very green behind the ears...

I'll have some undefined number of mongoDB collections (currently 2) to seed and want to build a dynamic dry script for this and future projects.

This code/script works but seems redundant with the repeated block of code for each collection. I thought it should be possible to loop through a list of mongoDB collections with one block of code dynamically changing the collection name. However, I can't figure out how to make that work. The second block of code is my failed attempt (criticism on the working and non working code is welcomed - it's the only way to improve):

```
// empties the mongoDB collections and inserts fresh seed data
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const db = require("../modelsMongoose");
const seedObj = require("../db/noSql/seeds"); // seed objects

mongoose.connect(
    process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost:27017/dev_nosql",
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
);

db.User.deleteMany({})
    .then(() => db.User.collection.insertMany(seedObj.User))
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(`user document: ${data.result.n} records populated!`);
    })
    .then(() => mongoose.disconnect())
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    });

db.Activity.deleteMany({})
    .then(() => db.Activity.collection.insertMany(seedObj.Activity))
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(`activity document: ${data.result.n} records populated!`);
    })
    .then(() => mongoose.disconnect())
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

I know this code will not run (vscode feedback) but it explains the concept of what I'm trying to achieve. I attempted to prepend with ['db.' + collectionName] and ['seedObj.' + collectionName] which vscode liked, to no avail. Thanks for the help! -Bill

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const db = require("../modelsMongoose");
const seedObj = require("../db/noSql/seeds"); // seed objects

mongoose.connect(
    process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost:27017/dev_nosql",
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
);

// loop array of mongoDB collection
Object.keys(mongoose.connection.collections).forEach(e => { 
    let collectionName = e.substring(1, 0).toUpperCase() + e.substring(1, e.length); 

    db.[collectionName].deleteMany({})
        .then(() => db.[collectionName].collection.insertMany(seedObj.[collectionName]))
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(`user document: ${data.result.n} records populated!`);
        })
        .then(() => mongoose.disconnect())
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            process.exit(1);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a simpler way of doing this.

I am grabbing the code straight from my project in production here.

You can create a module just for handling DB connection.

I called it `dbConection.js`

```js
/*eslint-env node*/

//Dependencies
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Winston Logger
const dbLog = require('./logger').get('dbCon');

//Require Models for DB
require('../models/Chat_History');
require('../models/User');
require('../models/benchmark');

//Global Variables
const MongodbPass = require('../creds/mongoKey');

//Connect to DB
const DB_Connection = mongoose.createConnection(MongodbPass.Database, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
});

//Initiate the connection
DB_Connection
    .once('open', () => dbLog.info('DB Connected'))
    .catch(err => dbLog.error('Error Connecting to DB' + ' ' + err));


//Load Models for Chat DB
const Chat_DB = DB_Connection.model('chat');

//Load Models for User DB
const User_DB = DB_Connection.model('user');

//Load Models for Bench DB
const Bench_DB = DB_Connection.model('bench');

//Export them all
module.exports = { Chat_DB, User_DB, Bench_DB };
```

One of the example models:

```js
//Dependencies
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//Global Constant
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const ChatSchema = new Schema({
    channelId: {
        type: String
    },
    chatHistory: {
        type: Array,
        profImg: {
            type: String,

        },
        time: {
            type: String

        },
        msg: {
            type: String,

        },
        sender: {
            type: String,

        },
        timeStamp: {
            type: Date,

        }
    },

}, {
    collection: 'Chat'
});

mongoose.model('chat', ChatSchema);
```

How you can actually use the module in the other file

```js
//Load DB models
const DB_Connection = require('../path/to/dbConnection');

const chatDB =  DB_Connection.Chat_DB;
const userDB = DB_Connection.User_DB;
const benchDB = DB_Connection.Bench_DB;

//Query Different Collection on the fly.

    chatDB.find({})
    .then(result=>console.log(result))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));

    userDB.find({})
    .then(result=>console.log(result))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));


    benchDB.find({})
    .then(result=>console.log(result))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! This both answers and doesn't answer my question. It doesn't explain how I can dynamically seed the data structure I currently have, but it does show that cleaner definition makes the code much more readable. In my desire to have the system dynamically create models and seeding, the ability to understand what's happening gets obscured. I really appreciate the real world examples. Thanks, -Bill

Comment: You're welcome. But why do you want to dynamically change the collection name though?

Comment: I have an index.js in the models folder that dynamically creates the models from existing files. Similarly, I have index.js in the seeds folder that dynamically creates the seeding objects (with matching file names). Create a model and a seed file in the appropriate folders and the objects are in the exported. I thought it would be interesting if I didn't have create an individual block of code for the seeding. I can loop the collection names, but I couldn't find a way to make the code work dynamically. It's moot point because of the complexity, but I'd still like to know if it's possible.

Comment: Ok, I think it might be doable. What do you mean be 'seeds' here? Just to better understand your approach.

Comment: Furthermore, you can perhaps open another question specifically about this as the redundancy part has already been solved.

Comment: Seeds are fake data for testing, I create functions using https://github.com/Marak/faker.js to create testing data. The initial question was about: db.[aVariableToWorkHere].deleteMany({}) so I wouldn't repeat code blocks